# Pass value from flow to custom component and handle change

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura-attribute, design-attributes

I am new here and have a question about flow. I am passing value to my aura component with design, but I cannot handle change. I am passing value from text field to my custom component, but it doesnt changes on user input.Its just empty field. Help me, please.
Actually is it even possible to get user input on the same screen? I can display it  only on the next.

## Component

```html
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens">
    <aura:attribute name="requiredField" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.requiredField}" action="{!c.HandleRequiredFieldChange}"/>
</aura:component>
```

## Controller JS

```js
({
    handleNavigate: function(cmp, event) {
        var navigate = cmp.get("v.navigateFlow");
        navigate(event.getParam("action"));
    },
    changeValue : function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.requiredField", 'false');
    },
    HandleRequiredFieldChange : function (component, event, helper) {
        var params =  event.getParams();
        alert(params.value);
    }
});
```

## Design

```xml
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="requiredField" label="Required field value" />
</design:component>
```

[image: Aura component used within screen flow]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help). You mention a Flow but do not share any screen shots or details of the Flow. Also, what do you mean when you say that you "cannot handle the change"? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/358619/edit) your question to add this (and possibly more) info.

Comment: @Moonpie  thanks, edited!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your text input to the custom Aura component via the requiredField parameter.

Where it says: "Required Field Name" you should reference your text field, search for it. Also you should **not** select "Manually Assign Variables (Advanced) in the "Advanced" tab of the component.